# IIS Config - PROPFIND, OPTIONS verbs are ignored and treated as GETs?

Tags: asp.net, iis, webdav

I'm attempting to configure a webdav server example application (https://sourceforge.net/projects/webdav/) to run on IIS6 (Win2003 Server). The application runs correctly on my dev machine (Win7, IIS7.5).

When I attempt to map a drive to the DAV share, several requests are issued, including one OPTIONS request and two PROPFIND requests.

In Fiddler, I see that these are transmitted correctly. However, the response is always the content of the default page on the site. If I look at the IIS logs, the requests are logged as GETs instead of OPTIONS or PROPFIND.

UrlScan is disabled, but I went ahead and added OPTIONS and PROPFIND to the list of allowed verbs (since I'm running out of ideas).

Help.

Comment: We've also faced this problem with WebDAV integration. Our production machines run Windows Server 2008, so we decided to forget about this issue for now. Nevertheless, I'm interested in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved.

Turns out that URLScan wasn't disabled, though it was not listed in the ISAPI filter list in IIS Manager. Just for kicks I renamed the URLScan.ini file, which resulted in an exception when any site on the server was hit.

Rather than removing URLScan completely (following the Prime Directive), I modified the denyVerbs and DenyHeaders sections to allow all of the DAV stuff.

I'll accept an answer from the first person to provide a clear explanation of what security problems this may introduce if put in production.